# Error APK when built with key store

Tags: android

My app run very good when built test but when build it with keystore and run my app it  force close and show error

```html
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                   java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                       at tuannt.appweather.f.f.a(Unknown Source)
                                                       at tuannt.appweather.e.a.a(Unknown Source)
                                                       at tuannt.appweather.e.a.onPostExecute(Unknown Source)
                                                       at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:631)
                                                       at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
                                                       at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:644)
                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:150)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5162)
                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:744)
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
                                                       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

What happened with my apk?

Comment: U have applied proguard? and handled proguard for your package?

Comment: What is this? I not understand?

Comment: You got NPE and make sure you given permission in manifest (INTERNET)

Comment: tuannt.appweather.f.f.a is ur package? U have excluded ur package in proguard file

Comment: I did it, in build.gradle I change  minifyEnabled true to  minifyEnabled false
Thank you very much